# OpenCV 3.X Timing Function Calls using UMAT

Tags: performance, opencv, opencl, timing

I am trying to perform a gpu vs. cpu evaluation of cv::remap() on my computer. 
To do so, I was trying to average the time over max_count calls.

```
for(int count = 0; count < max_count; count++)
{
auto t0 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        cv::remap(cv_im_gpu, cv_im_gpu_remap, map1_gpu, map2_gpu, CV_INTER_LINEAR);
auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
time += t1 - t0;
}
average_time = time / max_count;
```

What I observed was that the first iteration took around 100ms (1024x768 pixel input image) and supsequent iterations took 0ms. Do I have to perform some kind of snychronization or what is the reason for this behaviour? Calling the same function with cv::Mat instead of cv::UMat works just as expected and every iteration contributes roughly the same amount of time.

I am running the code on a windows 7 plattform with an ATI 360m graphics card using OpenCV 3.1.0.

Thanks.

Comment: I think that the first time, the OpenCL code has to be compiled that's why you observe this. Other calls of `cv::remap` with `UMat` do not need to compile the remap OpenCL code as it should be save somehow.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Catree. I know that the compilation takes some time when the function is launched for the first time. What I do not understand is why subsequent iterations do not contribute anything ot the time variable?

Comment: I suppose the binary kernel is saved somewhere in order to avoid to compile each time. More information: [Online/Offline Compilation](https://www.fixstars.com/en/opencl/book/OpenCLProgrammingBook/online-offline-compilation/).

Comment: Yes, thank you for the link. That is why iteration nr. 0 takes some time. But why do iteration nr. 1 to max_count contribute no time? The remap function shouldn´t take less than 1ms on my GPU (which is what I measure at the moment).

Comment: Have you checked the result? Call the GPU function once to eliminate the timing of the online compilation and then call multiple of times the GPU functions with different data. If the results are ok, maybe it is just that the GPU function has been correctly optimized. Or increase the input image size? When the image data has been correctly loaded into the GPU memory, it makes sense to me that the computation should be quite fast on the GPU.

Comment: I ran the operation with a much larger image size and it takes around the same time to compute the results. I also changed the input data in every iteration and stored the results. The behaviour is still the same. I think it launches the operations in parallel and therefore it seems that fast.
It´s just weird that this is not the case for all opencl implementations that opencv provides. If I run "warpPerspective(...)" in a loop, the execution time for the GPU is roughly half of the execution time on the CPU - in every iteration.

Comment: If the computation is done in parallel in background, that means that you cannot get the result immediatly after the call of the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by adding a clWaitForEvents(...) in the OpenCV code. Thank you.